# Mutli-tenancy Vs Single tenancy

Tags: http, tomcat, multi-tenant

I want to know the difference between multi-tenancy and single tenancy.
Is tomcat supporting mutli-tenancy .Can you explain both with an example.
I am asking this question in context to http-servers.

Answer (score 0):

#### Definition

[From Wiki definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)

> In a multitenancy environment, multiple customers share the same application, running on the same operating system, on the same hardware, with the same data-storage mechanism. The distinction between the customers is achieved during application design, thus customers do not share or see each other's data.

So you can imagine that single tenancy is the other way around.

#### Example

Let's take JIRA as an example,

If you use [OnDemand JIRA Service](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/10/press-release-atlassian-announces-all-new-ondemand-service-for-product-development-and-collaboration/), it is multi-tenant, cloud-based service.

If you download [JIRA Standalone](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/download) and install it for you organisation. It is single tenancy case.

#### Designing multi-tenancy software

Designing multi-tenancy software is nothing to do with the hosting technology. It's actually about the way you architect the software.

Tomcat in your case, is absolutely suitable for multi-tenancy software.